# get the matching part out of cloudant json

Tags: json, view, couchdb, cloudant

I'm working with cloudantDB as DB for my spring application.

The thing that I'm trying to do is:

- check if there is a timeslot and topic in the document
- if there is a topic filled in:
- check the userId who has submitted that topic and return all of the items for that user.

```html
{
  "_id": "393c7748cf487f7c5223839dfdf5adf9",
  "_rev": "2-889c6d9d14fcc3c90a00e91aca5f2f4c",
  "name": "conference 1",
  "type": "conference",
  "location": "conf loc",
  "tag": "confTag",
  "startDate": "2015-05-04T22:00:00.000+0000",
  "endDate": "2015-05-08T22:00:00.000+0000",
  "timeslots": {
    "8a03b160-48e3-4f99-be38-2a2da34e5890": {
      "id": "8a03b160-48e3-4f99-be38-2a2da34e5890",
      "startDate": "2015-04-07T10:45:00.000+0000",
      "endDate": "2015-05-07T12:45:00.000+0000",
      "location": "Location",
      "topic": {
        "id": "4ad235ef-5938-4461-8a2e-346bf105c5b6",
        "title": "wa nen coole title",
        "description": "dees is een goei omschrijving",
        "tags": "cloud, tag",
        "attachment": "file.exe",
        "speakerId": null
      }
    },
    "a59b1dfd-d1c5-491f-bc02-807e38595ba4": {
      "id": "a59b1dfd-d1c5-491f-bc02-807e38595ba4",
      "startDate": "2015-05-05T10:00:00.000+0000",
      "endDate": "2015-05-05T11:15:00.000+0000",
      "location": "mlkjs",
      "topic": {
        "id": "8b753adb-9a15-486f-9209-b9cc5ef134a1",
        "title": "test132",
        "description": "met speakerId",
        "tags": "sldkjf",
        "attachment": "kklsjdf",
        "speakerId": "speaker"
      }
    },
    "080153e7-f8bc-453e-b49a-a1df4679ceef": {
      "id": "080153e7-f8bc-453e-b49a-a1df4679ceef",
      "startDate": "2015-05-09T11:30:00.000+0000",
      "endDate": "2015-05-09T13:30:00.000+0000",
      "location": "file upload",
      "topic": {
        "id": "e3533a60-a0ba-4439-a9e9-b29e69be47db",
        "title": "fdgdfg",
        "description": "fdsgdsggdfgdfg",
        "tags": "dfgsdg",
        "attachment": null,
        "speakerId": null
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultTwitterText": "Hallo",
  "twitterUrl": "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?button_hashtag=confTag&text=Hallo"
}
```

So far I have this:

```
function(doc) {
{ if (doc.type === 'conference') {
    if(doc.timeslots.size !==0 ){
            emit( null, doc);
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think you might want something like:

```
function (doc) {
    if (doc.type == 'conference'){
    if (doc.timeslots){
            for (var i in doc.timeslots) {
                if(doc.timeslots[i].topic){
                    emit(doc.timeslots[i].topic.speakerId, doc.timeslots[i])
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

that'll make a view of `key:speaker, value: topic object`, which you can then query with `?key=speaker` to see the list of all the topic objects for the speaker.